# Firmware version K.15.15.XXXX for HP J9477A Switch E8206zl not found

Tags: hp, firmware, hpe

Does anyone know where I can find any K.15.15.XXXX firmware version for HP J9477A Switch E8206zl switch?

I could get my hands on K.15.18.0021 but the release notes is not helping me regarding the BootROM version. It says that the BootRom will also be upgraded to K.15.30 but it also says if I run a firmware version below K.15.15.xxxx (which I do), then I should first upgrade to firmware version K.15.15.xxxx
This is why I'm scared to boot on secondary flash with version K.15.18.0021.

My actual switch software/firmware information:

```
SWHP# sh ver
Management Module 1: Standby
Image stamp:    /sw/code/build/btm(K_15_06)
                Sep  2 2011 14:34:17
                K.15.06.0006
                143
Boot Image:     Primary

Management Module 2: Active
Image stamp:    /sw/code/build/btm(K_15_06)
                Sep  2 2011 14:34:17
                K.15.06.0006
                143
Boot Image:     Primary
```

---

```
SWHP# sh flash
Image             Size (bytes) Date     Version
----------------- ------------ -------- --------------------
Primary Image    :    14841334 09/02/11 K.15.06.0006
Secondary Image  :    14533716 02/20/19 K.15.18.0021

Boot ROM Version : K.15.19
Default Boot     : Primary
```

Thank you in advance for saving my life :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The K.15.15.0006 release is available here: https://asp.arubanetworks.com/downloads;products=Aruba%20Switches;softwareGroups=ArubaOS-Switch;productSeries=HPE%208200%20zl%20Switch%20Series;softwareMajorVersions=15.15

Their search doesn't seem to work.